# TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/animations'?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm trying to integrate and Use angular-material (i.e., https://material.angular.io/). I have followed the steps which angular have provided on the site. But, I'm getting a syntactical error message saying cannot find module BrowserAnimationsModule. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Following is snapshot of error:

[image]

**Package.json for the package version I'm using:**

[image]

Comment: Which versions of the Angular packages are you using?

Comment: Did you maybe forget to install the animations npm package? 'npm install --save @angular/animations'

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi I have added the package.json, hope you get a clear picture now.

Comment: 1. Why do you keep posting *screenshots* of code?! 2. And why are you mixing and matching Angular package versions?

Comment: @jonrsharpe package.json snapshot is for the question you've asked like which version m using, So by showing you the package.json you can get a clear view that what m doing wrong secondly, I didn't got your second question that why am i mixing and matching angular package

Comment: @SumitKhanduri What he means by "mixing and matching" is you are using **Angular 2** with **Angular 4**. Try updating your dependencies via `npm update`.